# Serve web page on named local URL

Tags: node.js, ip

I know that on a local network, it is possible to redirect from the default port to another port like so, and run an application:

```
# Routes all traffic from port 80 to port 3000
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
node .
```

For clients to access the service, typing `11.0.120.131` will have the same effect as typing `11.0.120.131:3000` (if `11.0.120.131` is the IP of the computer running the node server).

I've seen in a couple cases where you can type into the address bar a *word*, e.g. `http://meetings` and it will actually pull up a web page (as if typing in an IP). I'm not sure what the technique is called, but I would like to achieve the same thing on my local network.

Is this possible on a Linux machine using a command similar or not to `iptables` above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLs are resolved to IP addresses via the Domain Name System. In order to create a fancy URL like `meetings`, some router between you and the DNS server looks for those particular URLs and resolves them to the correct IP address (or provisions your machine to use a custom DNS server which does the same thing).

If you want to achieve this behavior on your computer, you can edit the hosts file (on Linux, `/etc/hosts`). This file contains a list of explicit URL resolutions; if you put a URL in this file, such as `meetings`, then it will be resolved to the IP address you specify, without ever contacting a DNS server.

If you want all the computers on your network to use this behavior, you have to set up an actual DNS server for those URLs, and configure your router to specify it as the DNS server to use, which may not be possible depending on the brand of router.